# PYAUTOGUI in a Virtual Machine Solution

Tags: python, selenium, virtual-machine, pyautogui

**I'm planning to use pyautogui in a Virtual Machine**, and we all know this is not possible.
But i've found this topic concerning this : 
https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py
can anyone please tell me how can i implement this code in any script so that pyautogui works fine in VM ?
Thank you !